# Dynamic programming--Longest Common Substring: Understanding the space optimization

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am working through a ver typical question which is the Longest Common Substring of two strings.
The problem statement is quite clear:
for two string s1 and s2, find the length of their longest common substring.
I can understand the definition of the state represented by the dp array. It is a two-dimension array where two dimension just represents the index of the characters in each string(but just 1 based not 0 based).
The original solution code is like below which appears clear to me :

```java
  public int findLCSLength(String s1, String s2) {
    int[][] dp = new int[s1.length()+1][s2.length()+1];
    int maxLength = 0;
    for(int i=1; i <= s1.length(); i++) {
      for(int j=1; j <= s2.length(); j++) {
        if(s1.charAt(i-1) == s2.charAt(j-1)) {
          dp[i][j] = 1 + dp[i-1][j-1];
          maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, dp[i][j]);
        }
      }
    }
    return maxLength;
  }
```

This solution obviously can be optimized since the state of dp[i][j] just depends on the previous row which means two row will be sufficent for the dp array.
So I made the dp array a two-dimension one and use the mod operation to map the indexes in the range of 2.

```java
  static int findLCSLength(String s1, String s2) {
    int[][] dp = new int[2][s2.length()+1];
    int maxLength = 0;
    for(int i=1; i <= s1.length(); i++) {
      for(int j=1; j <= s2.length(); j++) {
        if(s1.charAt(i-1) == s2.charAt(j-1)) {
          dp[i%2][j] = 1 + dp[(i-1)%2][j-1];
          maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, dp[i%2][j]);
        }
      }
    }
    return maxLength;
  }
```

However my code didn't produce the correct answer for all test cases. I found one code snippet which gives correct answer on all test cases which has only one extra operation as I missed.

```java
  static int findLCSLength(String s1, String s2) {
    int[][] dp = new int[2][s2.length()+1];
    int maxLength = 0;
    for(int i=1; i <= s1.length(); i++) {
      for(int j=1; j <= s2.length(); j++) {

        //This is the only extra line I missed
        dp[i%2][j] = 0;

        if(s1.charAt(i-1) == s2.charAt(j-1)) {
          dp[i%2][j] = 1 + dp[(i-1)%2][j-1];
          maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, dp[i%2][j]);
        }
      }
    }
    return maxLength;
  }
```

One of the cases that my code fails is "passport" and "ppsspt", where my code produced 4 but the correct answer is obviously 3.
I am confused but this line , what does this line do and why it is necessary?
Hope anyone can help on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It resets the current count.

Your code sets this variable when:

```
if(s1.charAt(i-1) == s2.charAt(j-1)) {
```

But there's no else to set it to 0, which is effectively what that code does.

So consider when:

```
s1.charAt(i-1) != s2.charAt(j-1)
```

The previous value that you had in this array location will carry over to the next sub-string comparison when it shouldn't.